# How to add Checkbox to Kendo Grid's Toolbar?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to add a `checkbox` to the `Toolbar of a Kendo Grid`, but there is no configuration or sample on the Documentation. So, is it possible to add `checkbox` as button?

```
<script>
    var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        toolbar: [
            { name: 'excel', text: 'Export to Excel' },
            { type: 'checkbox', text: 'Get full list', id: "cbFull" } //it does not work
        ]
    //code omitted for brevity
<script>
```

Comment: You can create a toolbar template http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/toolbar-template

Comment: I tried but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
   <div class="toolbar">
      <input type="button" id="exportExcel" value="Export Excel"/>
      <label class="list-label" for="list">Get full list:</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="list" style="width: 75px"/>
   </div>
</script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
 toolbar: kendo.template($("#template").html())
 //code omitted for brevity

 var excelButton = grid.find("#exportExcel")
 excelButton.on("click",function(){
     alert("Saving...");
     grid.data("kendoGrid").saveAsExcel();
  });
});
</script>
```

Example http://dojo.telerik.com/iFodO (Export doesn't actually work as its missing JSZip)

Comment: Thanks a lot/ Do you have any idea how to retrieve data according to checkbox is clicked or not? I mean that if checkbox is clicked I want to pass a parameter and get the full list. If no, only the last 500 record. Any help pls?

Comment: You can change the dataSource filter. Bind to the change event of your checkbox, then change the grid dataSource filter http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-filter OR change the dataSource of the grid to come from a different source

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.